# Compare big data frame with small and add new column (big data) with result

Tags: r, compare, dataframe

We have "big data frame" and "small data frame". Var1s are my ID, and Var2s are some value.

```
df1 <- data.frame(row.names=1:10, var1=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"), var2=runif(10))
df2 <- data.frame(row.names=1:4, var1=c("B","D","K","A"), var2=runif(4))
```

I want to compare both data frame and receive new data.frame "DF", which look like: [head(DF)]

```
  var1      var2     Compare
1    A 0.7145085           1
2    B 0.9966129           1
3    C 0.5062709           0
4    D 0.4899432           1
5    E 0.6491614           0
6    F 0.8308064           0
```

I only want to compare df1$var1 with df2$var2.

The aim of this task is calculating the sum of var2 (from data frame df1), where compare=1.

I think about logical function, but this check only row by row...as you see I will have all "FALSE".

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. I suppose you have [searched](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+compare+two+data+frames)?

Comment: Hmm...I really don't know, why I get "3 minus"... Henrik, I don't have any idea, how I can do it and I also searched SO.

Comment: Because you are very unclear.  Use set.seed and edit your question.

Comment: If you "don't have any idea" of how "to compare df1$var1 with df2$var2" I strongly recommend you to read some introductory stuff, like [this](http://www.statmethods.net/management/operators.html), [this](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Basics/Indexing_into_a_data_structure/#indexing-with-a-boolean-vector) and [this](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Vector-arithmetic).

Comment: If english is a problem, make sure your examples are clear, reproducible, and fully describe what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could certainly improve this question (also notice I use `set.seed`?).  Here is one approach using `merge` and `apply` but I'm certain there's better ways:

```
set.seed(10)
df1 <- data.frame(row.names=1:10, var1=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"), var2=runif(10))
df2 <- data.frame(row.names=1:4, var1=c("B","D","K","A"), var2=runif(4))


df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by="var1", all=TRUE)
df3$Compare <- rowSums(apply(df3[, -1], 2, function(x) !is.na(x))) - 1
df3$var2 <- apply(df3[, 2:3], 1, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
df3[, c(1, 5, 4)]

##    var1       var2 Compare
## 1     A 1.10340351       1
## 2     B 0.95842417       1
## 3     C 0.42690767       0
## 4     D 1.26083983       1
## 5     E 0.08513597       0
## 6     F 0.22543662       0
## 7     G 0.27453052       0
## 8     H 0.27230507       0
## 9     I 0.61582931       0
## 10    J 0.42967153       0
## 11    K 0.11350898       0
```

Comment: Tyler Rinker, thx for your suggestion but I know function "merge" and probably you didn't understand me...I didn't want in new data frame "var1 K" and sum "var2 by df1 and df"2. I only wanted to check/compare df1 and df2 by var1. R has to check only var1 means ID and build new column names "Compare". Now, do you understand my problem ??

Comment: @Blazej : Your question was not clear. But this might help (if I understood your comments): `df1[df1$var1 %in% df2$var1,]`

Comment: @Matrics I think this is precisely what Blazej is after.  It was the use of the word `sum` that threw me off.  So `df1$Compare <- as.numeric(df1$var1 %in% df2$var1)` should give you exactly what you're after.

Comment: Thx Metrics and Tyler Rinker. It's exactly what I wanted :)